# When cas login successfully jumps, the targetUrl contains special characters

Tags: cas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlTlM.png)

As we can see in the pic.
http://localhost:8881/login?service=http://localhost:9280/cas/login?ddtab=true%26target%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9999%2F%23%2Findex
this is my cas login url .
but the target url has special characters like '#'. when the target url has special characters
the forward url  does not have the '#' left

How can I solve this problem ?

THANKS

BTW. I have tried encode my target url but it still wont work.

It seems the special characters disappear when cas server tries to redirect my url and add ticket to it.